# Where dose the snakeyaml.util package in jackson-dataformat-yaml moved to

Tags: fasterxml

I am updating an old project but find out the `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.util` package from `jackson-dataformat-yaml` no longer exists. I can't find any information where it gets moved to. If it is deleted, what is the recommended replacement? Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jackson-dataformat-yaml](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml) has been archived. Its successor is now [jackson-dataformats-text](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text).

By the way, which `jackson-dataformat-yaml` were you using? I could not find any `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.util` packages in versions `2.0` and above, the only sub-package I found was `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.error`.

So please give this one a try during your migration:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, it is the version 2.7.6 comes with the Dropwizard 1.0.2. The thing I want to use is an Uri encoder, so I think I will just switch to another library to encode Uri.

Comment: Ah ok, but I still can see no util package in the 2.7.x branch https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml/tree/2.7/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml - by the way feel free to upvote or accept my answer, to show others, that it was helpful to you.